# Sybase JDBC: Insert special characters

Tags: jdbc, character-encoding, sybase

`update <table >set <col> = 'é'`

won't work

é is replaced with question mark ? using JDBC com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
and connection string

> `jdbc:sybase:Tds:<host>:<port>/<database>`

same problem with Oracle ..

I tried adding ?charset=iso_1 to connection URL

I tried prepared statement and exteuteUpdate

it works when i execute the query with isql or with another tool like dbArtisan using the 3 drivers available within it

I can retrieve and display accented characters using javascript or php htmlentities function. The problem is with insert/update

sybase db is in iso_1

```
sp_helpsort
Character Set = 1, iso_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed to tell that i use php and Javabridge

> `java_set_file_encoding("ISO-8859-1");`

resolved the problem